# org mode pdf export error "Wrong type argument: sequencep 108"

Tags: emacs, pdf-generation, org-mode

I'm using emacs version 25.2 on a MacBook Pro (OS X 10.12).  When I try to export an org document to pdf, I get the message above.  If I export to latex, it works OK, and I can then use pdflatex to create the pdf I expect.
I must have set something wrong, but I can't work out what!
Exporting to other formats, e.g., ODT, html, works as expected.
Thanks very much!

Comment: Set the variable `debug-on-error` to `t` and try again. Then post the backtrace.

Comment: You might find https://emacs.stackexchange.com/ a better venue for org-mode questions.

Comment: Thanks to Nick.  I found the problem, and then used the settings provided by Britt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might check the value of the variable `org-latex-pdf-process`. You can do that with `C-h v`. It may be doing something different than what you are doing by hand. Mine for example reads:

```
(setq org-latex-pdf-process '("pdflatex -interaction nonstopmode %f" "biber %b" "pdflatex -interaction nonstopmode %f" "pdflatex -interaction nonstopmode --synctex=-1 %f"))
```